# R for-loop and lists with non-numeric argument to binary operator error

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, numeric

Thank you in advance for you time in helping me with my problem.

I am trying to write a program to calculate the standard difference of several different groups and the last step has me a little stumped.

```
data<- read.dta("FinalRfile.dta")
Data<-data
grouplist<-16
grange<-range(Data[grouplist])
groupnum<-grange[2]-grange[1]+1
groupnums<-(1:groupnum)

groupmean<-list()
for (i in groupnums) groupmean[[i]]<-sapply(subset(Data, Data[grouplist] == i),mean)

groupvar<-list()
for (i in groupnums) groupvar[[i]]<-sapply(subset(Data, Data[grouplist] == i),var)
#creating a matrix of the all possible combinations that do not repeat
totcombs<-combn(groupnum,2)
# creating variable for total number of columns, which are total number of combinations
ncombs<-ncol(totcombs)
ncols<-(1:ncombs)


gbias<-list()
# The code below is the section causing the problem
for (i in ncombs) gbias[[i]]<-(groupmean[totcombs[1,i]]-groupmean[totcombs[2,i]])/((groupvar[totcombs[1,i]]-groupvar[totcombs[2,i]])^(.5))

Error in groupmean[totcombs[1, i]] - groupmean[totcombs[2, i]] : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Basically I am trying to use a formula "(mean_1-mean_2/sqrt(variance_1-variance_2)) with the variables in the list groupmean and groupvar with all possible combinations. e.g. group 1&2,1&3,1&4,1&5,2&4, and etc. Below is an example of the setup of the lists to help

```
>groupmean[1]
[[1]]
         zid     tookphys        black       income          age       female 
3.729809e+05 6.303419e-01 1.783806e-01 8.128384e+03 2.498148e+01 5.080128e-01 
     educdec          num          mhi        disea        child      xghindx 
1.177905e+01 4.027778e+00 7.684203e+01 1.109670e+01 4.209402e-01 7.283730e+01 
     afairnm       ghinnm     xghindx2     planlist 
9.396368e-01 8.173077e-01 5.531082e+03 1.000000e+00    

> totcombs
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

Later note:
Ok with peoples help. I have gotten to the point where it returns a value. Some values are NaN tho any ideas. Thanks again.

```
group1<-totcombs[1,]
group2<-totcombs[2,]


gbias<-list()
    > for (i in ncols) gbias[[i]]<-abs(groupmean[[group1[i]]]-groupmean[[group2[i]]])/(sqrt((groupvar[[group1[i]]]+groupvar[[group2[i]]])/2))
> 
> gbias
[[1]]
        zid    tookphys       black      income         age      female 
0.122500336 0.090412751 0.015108219 0.049922006 0.006736868 0.018827112 
    educdec         num         mhi       disea       child     xghindx 
0.092545644 0.077577473 0.010293535 0.069193643 0.019816257 0.074608054 
    afairnm      ghinnm    xghindx2    planlist 
0.029083388 0.133190608 0.063947169         Inf
```

Comment: make the question reproducible to get faster (any?) answers

Comment: You are trying to subtract a list (`groupmean[totcombs[2,i]]`) from a list (`groupmean[totcombs[1,i]]`). Won't work. It might be as simple as replacing the outer "[" call with call to "[[".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is, well, not the best way to do it, to put it lightly. The most immediate problem is that you are using single brackets (`[`) to select from the list `groupmean` when you almost certainly want to use double brackets (`[[`).

```
for (i in ncombs) gbias[[i]]<-(groupmean[[totcombs[1,i]]]-groupmean[[totcombs[2,i]]])/((groupvar[[totcombs[1,i]]]-groupvar[[totcombs[2,i]]])^(.5))
```

But, since you didn't really make this reproducible, it is hard to test.

Comment: The code runs, but returns null values. I normally work with Stata, but I am trying to learn and use R. I am sure there is a better way, but I do not know how. Thank for the attempt. ere is a link to the file from google docs. [link to file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-NtxB01L-9LX2Y5cGRvSlNzRzQ/edit?usp=sharing)                                                                     > for (i in ncombs) gbias[[i]]<-(groupmean[[totcombs[1,i]]]-groupmean[[totcombs[2,i]]])/((groupvar[[totcombs[1,i]]]-groupvar[[totcombs[2,i]]])^(.5))
> gbias[1]
[[1]]
NULL

> gbias[2]
[[1]]
NULL

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the for-loop to index through each of the columns in totcombs. You set up for this by assigning the number of columns in totcombs to ncombs, then assign a list of the numbers from 1 to ncombs to the varible ncols. So the for-loop should begin:

for (i in ncols)

However, in your code the result would be that the for-loop would execute just once with the index i equal to 10. This doesn't explain why R is complaining of a non-numeric argument to a binary operator.

Comment: yes you are correct, in this case there were 10 possible combinations of groups. ncols is (1:10) and I want the index to indicate the column of totcombs. I set the row as a number so it will not change. The process is the group from row 1 column 1 minus the group from row 2 column 1... with the column changing.